# django-filter return null queryset when wrong parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I'm creating a simple API.

models.py

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    tenor = models.IntegerField(db_column="tenor_field")
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=6, db_column="currency_field")
    value = models.FloatField(db_column="value_field")
```

serializer.py

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = [ 'tenor', 'currency', 'value']
```

views.py

```
class TestView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    filterset_fields  = ['tenor','currency']
```

when I call

https://10.1.33.70/api/v1/base-rates/floating/?currency=**EUR**&tenor=**10**

I get

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "tenor": 10,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "value": 0.6
    }
]
```

and it is ok.

When I call
https://10.1.33.70/api/v1/base-rates/floating/?currency=**EUR**&tenor=**xxx**

I get

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "tenor": [
        "Enter a number."
    ]
}
```

and it's also ok, because tenor is integer.

But when I call https://10.1.33.70/api/v1/base-rates/floating/?currency=**USD**&tenor=**10**

I get

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[]
```

because in database are only EUR position (not USD).

Is it possible to get a "HTTP 400 Bad Request" if I give a value to the "currency" parameter that is not in the database or can I define what values ​​can be given to the parameter and otherwise a "HTTP 400 Bad Request".

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add validate method in your TestSerializer with your conditions what you want to allow.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation

Comment: Thx, I try add     def validate_currency(self, currency):
        if currency != 'PLN':
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Wrong parameter!')  but it's doesn't work

Comment: If you use serializer to validate query params, make sure passing the data using request.query_params into serializer, not request.data.  
Code: `serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.query_params)`